# how can I convert string into HTML. I want the actual href to show/display instead of the text

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I convert string into HTML. I want the actual href to show/display instead of the text.

```
    var zzz = "test";
    var value0 = 14251876;
    var value1 = "AAAA";

    var EmailSubject = 'Transcription Assigned   Due (' + zzz + ')';                    
    var EmailBody = 'Dear ' + zzz + ',\n\n' + 'A dictation for the following Service has been assigned to you;\n\n' + 'Service Name: ' + zzz + '\n\n' + 'Thank you,\n' + 'Assessments\n' + '(416) 111 - 2222';  
    EmailBody = EmailBody + $($.parseHTML('<div><a href="/Apps/app_editevent.jsp?eventid=' + value1 + '" target="_blank">' + value0 + '</a></div>'));
    send_msg(false,'',20,0,'mailer@test.ca',1081636,'',EmailSubject,EmailBody);
```

Comment: What is send_msg exactly?

Comment: It is a server side function which triggers an email to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `.append()` it as HTML.

```js
var zzz = "test";
var value0 = 14251876;
var value1 = "AAAA";
var EmailSubject = 'Transcription Assigned   Due (' + zzz + ')';

var mailText = 'Dear ' + zzz + ',\n\n' + 'A dictation for the following Service has been assigned to you;\n\n' + 'Service Name: ' + zzz + '\n\n' + 'Thank you,\n' + 'Assessments\n' + '(416) 111 - 2222';

var $mailBody = $('<div>', {
  text: $('<p>', {
    text: mailText
  }).html()
});

var $href = $('<div>').append($('<a>', {
  href: '/Apps/app_editevent.jsp?eventid=' + value1 + '',
  target: '_blank',
  text: value0
})).appendTo($mailBody);

$('body').append($mailBody);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't create $('p') and $('div'). All i can do is to call send_msg function.

Comment: I just gave you an example. Can't you send HTML in this function?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do but I am not getting the link. I am getting <div><a href="/Apps/app_editevent.jsp?eventid=14251876" target="_blank">AAAA</a></div>

Comment: The browser should automatically understand the HTML you send as mail body. I have updated my answer. Send `EmailBody2` to your method, just as i did here, and see what happens, please.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `$($.parseHTML())` bits and just add the string itself.

Comment: I did that but then i get <div><a href="/Apps/app_editevent.jsp?eventid=' + value1 + '" target="_blank">' + value0 + '</a></div>' when it display the info.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method of jquery

```
string a = '<div id="send"></div>';
var html = $(a);
```

I guess This will Work and HTML will be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `append` to add it as  html to your div as

```
$('div').append('<div><a href="/Apps/app_editevent.jsp?eventid=' + value1 + '" target="_blank">' + value0 + '</a></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting link of href.

```
var zzz = "test";
var value0 = 14251876;
        var value1 = "AAAA";
        var EmailSubject = 'Transcription Assigned   Due (' + zzz + ')';
        var EmailBody = 'Dear ' + zzz + ',\n\n' + 'A dictation for the following Service has been assigned to you;\n\n' + 'Service Name: ' + zzz + '\n\n' + 'Thank you,\n' + 'Assessments\n' + '(416) 111 - 2222';
        EmailBody = EmailBody + '<div><a href="/Apps/app_editevent.jsp?eventid=' + value1 + '" target="_blank">' + value0 + '</a></div>';
        document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = EmailBody;
```

Comment: Yes I am not getting the link. I am getting <div><a href="/Apps/app_editevent.jsp?eventid=14251876" target="_blank">AAAA</a></div>

Comment: Just removed $($.parseHTML(), It work for you try it.

Comment: I get TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: You have to create div with inner id.

Comment: I can't create, I can only pass parameters to the function send_msg

Comment: My example working perfectly, what doing your method.

Answer (score 0):

Just removed parseHTML, It will work for you.

```
        var zzz = "test";
        var value0 = 14251876;
        var value1 = "AAAA";
        var EmailSubject = 'Transcription Assigned   Due (' + zzz + ')';
        var EmailBody = 'Dear ' + zzz + ',\n\n' + 'A dictation for the following Service has been assigned to you;\n\n' + 'Service Name: ' + zzz + '\n\n' + 'Thank you,\n' + 'Assessments\n' + '(416) 111 - 2222';
        EmailBody = EmailBody + '<div><a href="/Apps/app_editevent.jsp?eventid=' + value1 + '" target="_blank">' + value0 + '</a></div>';
         send_msg(false,'',20,0,'mailer@test.ca',1081636,'',EmailSubject,EmailBody);
```